# Firefox doesn't recognize if video src gets interrupted

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, video.js

i'm currently playing around with video.js to make video watching a bit more reliable. The current case if: while watching a video, the connection gets interrupted (loss of internet connectivity).

With chrome it was no big deal: I created a function, attached the function to the error event and voila, if an error occurred, my function was able to recover (in this case its just trying to reload the video and seek to the last known position).

On firefox nothing happened at all. The error is never raised.
I tried to work around this a bit and noticed that firefox seems to think the file is fully loaded in case of a network interruption. So the bufferedPercent jumps to 1 and the loadedalldata event is also triggered. For me this seems to be just broken, but i'm unable to nail it down to a firefox or a video.js problem.

Anyone else having such problems or knows a better way to handle such problems?

Background info: to test the case, i run a HAProxy infront of two webservers running nginx who deliver the video files. To trigger my problem, i just kill the nginx which is currently delivering the stream. So a reconnect should work fine (as long as the other one is still working of course ;)

Thanks and regards,
Darkman

Comment: Are you using just mp4? or webm too?

Comment: Both. I also tried to reorder (mp4 before webm and vice versa), no change. I also can try only one of it if that matters. But both support seeking (tested), just in case this might be the reason why you ask ;)

Comment: Do your server and proxy support HTTP byte serving? i.e., is there an "Accept-Ranges" response header?

Comment: yep, checked a few times. I see the requests when using the web developer console and also the replies, they both look fine so far. The haproxy also just does only tcpmode as i don't want any useless interceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are binding the error on the video tag and not the source tag?
As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video):

> Instead of the error event being dispatched to the media element itself, it now gets delivered to the child  elements corresponding to the sources resulting in the error.

```
<video controls id="videoTag" width="640" height="360" preload="auto">
<source src="pathto.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' id="mp4Source">
<source src="pathto.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"' id="webmSource">
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('mp4Source').addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
alert('mp4Source error');
}, false);
document.getElementById('webmSource').addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
alert('webmSource error');
}, false);
document.getElementById('videoTag').addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
alert('videoTag error');
}, false);
document.getElementById('videoTag').addEventListener('stalled', function(ev) {
alert('videoTag stalled');
}, false);

</script>
```

**EDIT:** also check for the stalled event as it triggers when one disconnects the network while the media resource is downloading. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When detecting playback/network errors on HTML5 video I normally use something that follows the code at end of this [section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#the-video-element).
Thanks

Comment: Well, but i read that this will not work if you use multiple "source" elements, like <video><source src="video.mp4"><source src="video.webm"></video>
Another point is, that if the source gets interrupted, firefox "thinks" the stream is completed. If you reload the site after the interrupt it will *not* reload the video at all (means it will abort at the same point due to the rest is still missing).

Comment: Ok, i tested your code, nothing. If i interrupt the download it just stops, no alert, nothing.

Comment: It should work if you bind the error on the source tag as explained on MDN website. Is this what you tried? When you catch the error it is then a matter of pushing a video.load() and video.play(). Though if you want the timecode on where in the timeline the error happened you need to make a routine to periodically save it. I have updated the code to reflect what I meant.

Comment: I tested my updated code and it works fine for detecting a network shutdown (like cutting the wifi) in firefox 28 or having an invalid mp4 source path.

Comment: i copied your code 1:1, chageing the files, run my test and still nothing. The progressbar jumps immedially to "full" when i kill the nginx and the video stops at the end of the data and the indicator jumps to the end like "finished with this file". I also tried a firefox28 portable for that, just to make sure the version matches. So something seems to be still wrong. As of typing: i'm having a proxy between my firefox and my destination, maybe thats also an issue :(

Comment: Yeah it could be that your case scenario does not cause an error event to be triggered for Firefox and he is just hanging to some unresolved HTTP requests. HTML5 video implementation is still very browser specific. Sorry this could not help with your issue. Maybe it will help others.

Comment: At least i'll try without a proxy in between again to see if that really matters. From my debugging, using a few events, firefox "thinks" that the file is completed (there was an event to get the amount of data already downloaded, it jumps from x to 100% and fires a "all data loaded" event), so at least the connection is not hanging around...

Well, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Okay, i tried it again without a proxy: funny thing was that i tested just with a mp4 file and the javascript immedially popped up that mp4Source has a problem (the firefox doesn't play mp4), so i added a webm source, which played nice but the interrupt wasn't detected. So basicly your code seems to work, but not for the case the video download gets interrupted. Somehow this seems to be broken...

Comment: I cannot try on a live Nginx server but if I kill my WAMP stack on my dev machine I can confirm that the error is not raised in Firefox while it is raised in Chrome. It looks like something that could be submitted to the attention of the Firefox developers. If detecting this case scenario is critical for your project you could imagine to make regular AJAX ping request to your server/proxy and if you can tell that for sure the server is down then force a video.load().