# How Can I Always Play HTML5 Audio Reliably on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio

When working with an `<audio>` element (or `<video>` element, for that matter) without the `controls` attribute, mobile devices (both Android and iOS) usually require the user to tap on something in order for the `play()` call to actually work. For example, this jQuery code will *not* work on most mobile devices:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#an_audio_element_without_controls')[0].play();
});
```

But this *will* work on most mobile devices:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#some_link').click(function() {
        $('#an_audio_element_without_controls')[0].play();
        return false;
    });
});
```

After a specific `<audio>` element has been `play()`'d once, it can be `play()`'d again without the user having to first tap on something. So if you were in a situation where you needed to have certain audio files play at certain points of the user's workflow but didn't want them to always have to tap on something for the audio to play, you could have them tap on something at the very beginning and have that initial tap cause an empty `<audio>` element to play. Then whenever you actually needed to play audio, you could update that specific `<audio>` element's source and then play it and it would work.

This trick I have just described works well on iOS devices, but on some Android devices, it doesn't always work. For example, have a look at this code ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yxePT/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Android Audio Test</title>
        <style>
            .column {
                float: left;
                width: 18em;
            }

            .log {
                width: 16em;
                height: 10em;
                padding: 0.5em;
                overflow-y: auto;
                font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="column">
            <h1>Dynamic</h1>

            <p>
                This <code>&lt;audio&gt;</code> tag starts out having no
                <code>&lt;source&gt;</code> tags. Those tags get added when the
                user taps on the "Play Audio" link below. Each subsequent tap
                removes the <code>&lt;source&gt;</code> tags and re-adds them
                again. The audio isn't played until the amount of time
                specified in the "Timeout" dropdown menu has passed.
            </p>

            <p>
                Timeout:

                <select id="timeout">
                    <option value="0">None</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="40">40</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="70">70</option>
                    <option value="80">80</option>
                    <option value="90">90</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                    <option value="150">150</option>
                    <option value="200">200</option>
                    <option value="250">250</option>
                    <option value="300">300</option>
                    <option value="350">350</option>
                    <option value="400">400</option>
                    <option value="450">450</option>
                    <option value="500">500</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <audio id="audio_test_dynamic" data-log-id="audio_test_dynamic_log"></audio>

            <p><a href="javascript:click_handler_dynamic();">Play Audio</a></p>

            <div class="log" id="audio_test_dynamic_log"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <h1>Static</h1>

            <p>
                This <code>&lt;audio&gt;</code> tag's
                <code>&lt;source&gt;</code> tags are hard-coded.
            </p>

            <audio id="audio_test_static" data-log-id="audio_test_static_log">
                <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>

            <p><a href="javascript:click_handler_static();">Play Audio</a></p>

            <div class="log" id="audio_test_static_log"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var events = [
                'abort',
                'addsourcebuffer',
                'canplay',
                'canplaythrough',
                'cuechange',
                'durationchange',
                'emptied',
                'ended',
                'error',
                'loadeddata',
                'loadedmetadata',
                'loadstart',
                'mskeyadded',
                'mskeyerror',
                'mskeymessage',
                'onaddtrack',
                'onchange',
                'onmsneedkey',
                'onremovetrack',
                'pause',
                'play',
                'playing',
                'progress',
                'ratechange',
                'removesourcebuffer',
                'seeked',
                'seeking',
                'sourceclose',
                'sourceended',
                'sourceopen',
                'stalled',
                'suspend',
                'timeupdate',
                'update',
                'updateend',
                'updatestart',
                'volumechange',
                'waiting'
            ];

            $.each(events, function(index, event) {
                $('audio').on(event, function() {
                    $('#' + $(this).data('log-id')).prepend(event + '<br>');
                });
            });

            function click_handler_dynamic() {
                var timeout = parseInt($('#timeout').val(), 10);

                $('#audio_test_dynamic_log').prepend('---timeout set to ' + timeout + '---<hr>');

                $('#audio_test_dynamic').empty().html(
                    '<source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">' +
                    '<source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg">'
                );

                $('#audio_test_dynamic')[0].load();

                if (timeout) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#audio_test_dynamic')[0].play();
                    }, timeout);
                }
                else {
                    $('#audio_test_dynamic')[0].play();
                }
            }

            function click_handler_static() {
                $('#audio_test_static_log').prepend('<hr>');
                $('#audio_test_static')[0].play();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried the above code on a Motorola Xoom running the stock browser on Android 4.1.2. I found that if I load (or refresh) the page, leave the "Timeout" dropdown set to "None", and tap the "Dynamic" section's "Play Audio" link, it usually fails to play. I tried the same thing using various timeout options and found that it starts to get fairly reliable at around 200. It gets to be really reliable at around 400. I don't think I have seen 400 fail. The thing is, I don't want to find a number that never fails on this Motorola Xoom and then assume that it won't ever fail on any other device. I also don't want to have to have such a high delay before the audio plays. It would be nice if I could somehow detect when it's not playing and then force it to try playing again with a limit of five or ten attempts. I don't know what I could do to detect a failed play, though. The output of a successful play looks very similar to the output of a failed play, at least on the Motorola Xoom. Here is the output of a successful play (it's in reverse chronological order):

1. pause
2. ended
3. timeupdate (many times in a row)
4. durationchange
5. timeupdate
6. playing
7. canplaythrough
8. canplay
9. loadeddata
10. loadedmetadata
11. durationchange
12. progress
13. waiting
14. play
15. loadstart
16. emptied

The only difference between the output of a successful play and the output of a failed play is items 3 and 4 in the above list aren't there (the multiple `timeupdate`s and the `durationchange` that happens right before). If I tap the "Play Audio" link again after a failed play occurs and it fails again, this is what the output looks like (again, it's in reverse chronological order):

1. pause
2. playing
3. canplaythrough
4. canplay
5. loadeddata
6. loadedmetadata
7. durationchange
8. progress
9. waiting
10. play
11. loadstart
12. emptied
13. abort

If I tap the link enough times, it will eventually play.

Is there anything I can do to detect when a failed play occurs and have it try to play again?

Answer (score 1):

I have used HTML5 audio and video on Android devices and though I can tell the global experience is more reliable on iOS (due to less fragmentation and sometimes lesser design/horsepower) at some point you will need to rely on the manufacturer implementation of Android (though since Chrome is on Android I have to say things got better).

Normally you can bind to the error, abort or stalled event to detect playback/network issues and act on them (either display an error message or force load(), play()). See here for more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790921/firefox-doesnt-recognize-if-video-src-gets-interrupted/22813120#22813120).

I have seen Android devices took a dozen of seconds between the moment you touch play and the first timeupdate event where an iPad took 3 seconds ... without any error showing up.

Also I would suggest you bind to the touchstart event rather than the click event for Android touch based device.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the information. In the case of the Motorola Xoom (and I have seen this on another device too), the audio most definitely doesn't play, even after waiting for minutes.

Comment: Hum ... Have you  tried feeding it a wav file in a simpe audio tag? Are you trying in Chrome or the native android browser? I am a bit surprised a device like Xoom won't play anything ...

Comment: I'm referring only to Android's native / stock browser. As far as I can tell, it's not a problem in Chrome. Keep in mind that I'm also talking about the specific situation I described in the question (replacing an `<audio>` element's source and then trying to play it). Playing an `<audio>` element as-is (not messing with its source beforehand) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, when I tried to manage a few videos as a flow in an app I am doing with Cordova.js (webview) I have been experimenting weird behaviour when it comes into play video files through js, with no user interaction. Although I was **file.load()** and then triggering a **video.play()** when the video triggered a **canplaythrough** event, the **timeupdate** of that object shwod me that it stopped at **0** without any further event being triggered. Luckily I found this:

http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/78586868260/getting-the-html5-video-tag-to-work-in-cordova-for

what  pointed me to this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)

It looks to me like it is definitely what is going on here